# ERROR message : EXT4-fs error: ext4_find_entry 1451

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, ext4, fsck, nvme

I have a dell Xps 15 9550 and I have installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 in the UEFI dual boot along with Windows 10. Ubuntu works fine but after running for a while it goes to the black terminal screen with these errors:

[image: Image for error]

I tried doing fsck but I am not able to unmount `/dev/nvme0n1p8` as it says that the device is busy

It has SSD and the partitioning is:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1026048    1288191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1288192  315672247 314384056 149.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 315672248  648951642 333279395 158.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 982083584  983005183    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6 983005184 1000214527  17209344   8.2G Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p7 648951808  649537535    585728   286M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p8 649537536  948848639 299311104 142.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p9 948848640  982083583  33234944  15.9G Linux swap
```

Answer (score 2):

The file systems containing Ubuntu seems to be damaged. Please start from a Live DVD/USB, open a terminal (Alt+F2) and run:

```
sudo e2fsck -p /dev/nvme0n1p7
sudo e2fsck -p /dev/nvme0n1p8
```

This either fixes the issue or uncovers more underlying issues.

Comment: As you're a reputation 4 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!