# Hard drive error : EXT4-fs error - Failed to write entry, ignoring: Read-only file system

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, filesystem, ext4

I have a **Asus R556L**, running **Ubuntu 18.04LTS** on dual boot with Windows 10. The sata mode in the bios is AHCI.

Ubuntu works fine, but after working for a while, it goes to the black terminal screen with these errors, very similar to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/753108/error-message-ext4-fs-error-ext4-find-entry-1451/768813#768813). Windows works for some seconds and then I have a blue screen error and the PC reboots.

When I get this black screen the computer doesn't respond anymore and I have to reboot with the power button.

After reboot, I got the log files from the two previous boots with

```
journalctl -o short-precise -k
journalctl -o short-precise -k -b -1
```

They can be donwloaded at [last_reboot](http://partage.eleves.ens.fr//files/7a74ace50f7d3c20787f712fb6aac0d6/last_reboot.txt) and [previous_reboot](http://partage.eleves.ens.fr//files/ada7db21f78a07127d67d2616c9ff9ce/previous_reboot.txt).

There is one error that might be interesting (no usb device is plugged):

```
Cabirto kernel: usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

And also some of the kind:

```
Cabirto kernel: print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 922702400
```

I booted from a live CD to make some fix with the hard drive unmounted:

I tried to run

```
sudo e2fsck -p /dev/sda5
```

Which returns

```
/dev/sda5: clean, 785130/39829504 files, 54124587/159286528 blocks
```

(translated from French)

I ran a quick smart test `smartctl -t short /dev/sda` and `smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda` which gives

```
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3418
```

An extended smart test found no error.

Heres what `fdisk -l` shows (with loop devices removed):

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CD049B10-7DBD-4B39-912A-D7956EF0AE6A

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1023999    1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     1024000    1228799     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1228800    1261567      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     1261568  410861567  409600000 195,3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   666849280 1941141503 1274292224 607,6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  1941141504 1953523711   12382208   5,9G Linux swap
/dev/sda7   410861568  666849279  255987712 122,1G Microsoft basic data

Partition table entries are not in disk order.    

Disk /dev/sdb: 7,5 GiB, 8015314944 bytes, 15654912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0006aec1
```

EDIT : until this morning Windows worked fine but now I have a blue screen error and the PC reboots.

Edit : when modifying the grub menu as suggested in the comments, the message in the black screen changes and there 'ata' lines appear.

EDIT : Solution
In the end I sent my computer to ASUS technical services. They changed the motherboard. To what I understood, there was a connection problem. It was not a failing hard drive but filing wires or connectors.

[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI12t.jpg[image][image]

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: When I get the black screen I can't use my laptop anymore and I have to reboot it with the power button so I lose everything that wasn't saved. I would like not to have the black screen anymore

Comment: After reboot, can you try https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345978/92929 to retrieve log messages from the previous boot? It might contain the actual error.

Comment: I edited my post with two logs from the last and previous boot. It seems that there is a sector error, but I don't understand what it means and I don't get why SMART didn't find it...

Comment: Do you use the drive over a usb hub, or is it directly plugged into the machine?

Comment: It is the internal drive of the laptopo I don't use a USB hub. Every USB port was empty until I booted from the USB key to do fixes with the hard drive unmounted.

Comment: Some Asus systems need boot parameter to prevent run away log files. How to install Ubuntu on ASUS F556U, JournalError error?  add pci=nomsi 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079540/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-asus-f556u-journalerror-error/1081221#1081221

Comment: It didn't work. However I had two new lines in the black screen message. I edit my post with another photo.

Comment: What does the smartctl -a /dev/sda report? Some items in the table may be of interest for some failures.

Comment: Is it possible for you to check if the hdd is connected properly ? I know its in a laptop, bu these errors seem hardware related

Comment: pls post the output of `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/modules`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't even boot now. I'll try to change the hard drive and see...

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware problem. Try to unplug the harddrive and put it in. Sometimes that does the trick. I know it is a laptop, but it should not be that complecated. If you can affort it get a new SSD and a USB-housing for your current drive and backup everything to the new SSD.